# R POSIXct and as.Date

Tags: r, posixct, as.date

I have a date and time value which I'm using POSIXct to store in a variable. and when I use as.Date the date is different - why ?

```
x<-as.POSIXct("2012-02-25 19:00:00")
as.Date(x)
 [1] "2012-02-**26**"
```

Why is it incrementing day by 1?

Comment: What are your time zone and locale? See if you get the same with `x <- as.POSIXct("2012-02-25 19:00:00", tz = " ")`.

Comment: Yes I get the correct date, I'm in EST. what does tz="  " do?

Comment: It set the time zone as blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By simply using `x<-as.POSIXct("2012-02-25 19:00:00")` you will be setting the time zone, `tz`, to your current systems time zone, EST.

However when you use `as.Date` without declaring a time zone it will default to GMT. GMT is 5 hours ahead of EST so 25/02/2012 19:00 is 00:00 26/02/2012.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation